# How to communicate between Pi 3 and an Arduino using UART from GPIO?

Tags: raspbian, arduino, uart

I need to transfer data between Arduino and Pi. I have an Pi 3, and I used a simple circuit with a voltage divider to deal with 3.3v vs 5v logic levels. But I got nothing. Then, I used only Pi3 with its TX and RX pins connected directly. I saw [here](http://frillip.com/raspberry-pi-3-uart-baud-rate-workaround/) that Pi 3 uses another serial port to UART due bluetooth, and unlike pi 2, this UART port has a clock dependent baud rate. I saw [here](http://openenergymonitor.org/emon/node/12311) a solution where you disable bluetooth port to use it in UART, but I would like to use the native UART protocol attributed to GPIO's UART

I fixed as the link's tutorial stated and opened minicom. Everything I typed was echoed in minicom while TX and RX were connected, as soon as I disconnected them I got nothing on minicom. So I supposed my UART was working from GPIO pins. But with a logic analyzer I got nothing but trash, and my Arduino couldn't understand either.

Anyone has a clear tutorial on how to do this? I saw [here](http://www.briandorey.com/post/Raspberry-Pi-3-UART-Overlay-Workaround) a solution to Pi 3, but I got my OS from Noobs Version:1.9.0
Release date:2016-03-18. As seen in the last link, there's a solution for recent Raspbian images, but I got nothing. Anyone can confirm a clear e simple solutions to beginners?

I may have did something wrong at some tutorial, if this is the case, I would like what tutorial you guys used that lead to success.

Comment: Is there a reason you wouldn't use the USB link between the Pi and Arduino? Once you connect an arduino to a USB-aware machine, the latter detects a serial device, through which both can communicate.

Comment: You can check the Raspberry Pi's forum on the link given here: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=39839&p=326775 You will get the steps to communicate between Pi and arduino.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use one of the solutions mentioned in [How do I make serial work on the Raspberry Pi3](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/45570/how-do-i-make-serial-work-on-the-raspberry-pi3)

If it still doesn't work please include a photo of your set-up and the details of which serial port you are using.